# Push HEAD to remote branch, without having a local branch

Tags: git, workflow, git-branch, git-push, git-remote

Is it possible to push the checked-out history (a *detached HEAD*) to a remote branch, **without having a local branch checked-out?**

In case I need a corresponding local branch, I can checkout the remote one locally, later on. I do not need to track it; and I don't want to use a tag.

I tried `git push my_remote HEAD:my_remotebranch_name` but *git* tells me:

> error: unable to push to unqualified destination: my_remotebranch_name
>   The destination refspec neither matches an existing ref on the remote nor begins with refs/, and we are unable to guess a prefix based on the source ref.

How do I achieve it?

Comment: You need to be on some branch in the current repository in order to be able to push (exception: if you are pushing for the first time to an empty repo, nothing needs to exist remotely, but even in this case, you would still be on some branch).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+error%3A+unable+to+push+to+unqualified+destination

Comment: `git push my_remote HEAD:refs/heads/my_remotebranch_name`

Comment: @phd thank your for finding it out! Great!  You can add an answer so I can accept it (tomorrow?), or you can vote for duplicate (but I think the title of the question here is more clear about the use case than the question you linked).

Comment: @Kamafeather I've already voted for dup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to use a fully-qualified-name for the remote branch, to remove ambiguity and not make *git* try to guess.

```
git push my_remote HEAD:refs/heads/my_remotebranch_name
```

This will work event if *HEAD* is in a detached state (that was my case).

Thank you @phd.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood your question perfectly. This is what I understand: You want to push changes on your local git head to a remote branch, without actually creating a new branch on your local.

I tried doing that. I pulled a repo, made some changes and ran: `git push origin master:dummy` and also `git push origin HEAD:dummy2`

And it works fine. It creates a new branch in your remote repo and pushes the changes to there.